# Why does Android give the "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" error when the object is definitely not null?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` derived type that is supposed to download images to the device over http. To this end I pass it a `ContentDownloadService` which extends `IntentService.`

So in my `MainActivity.kt` I do this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private val Issues: ArrayList<Issue> = ArrayList<Issue>()

    private val downloadService: ContentDownloadService = ContentDownloadService()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadConfiguration();
        val issueCards: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.issues_list)
        issueCards.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        issueCards.adapter = IssueAdapter(Issues.toTypedArray(), this, downloadService)

    }
}
```

The `ContentDownloadService` is a fairly generic `IntentService` - as far as I know it isn't really relevant here because it is never called.

In the `IssueAdapter` we do this:

```
class IssueAdapter(private var issues: Array<Issue>, private val context: Context, private val downloadService: ContentDownloadService) : RecyclerView.Adapter<IssueAdapter.IssueViewHolder>() {


    class IssueViewHolder(public val cardView: CardView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int ) : IssueAdapter.IssueViewHolder {
        val issueView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.issue_card_view, parent, false)as CardView;
        return IssueViewHolder(issueView);
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IssueViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val issueView:CardView = holder.cardView
        val title : TextView = issueView.findViewById(R.id.issue_title)
        val image: ImageView = issueView.findViewById(R.id.issue_cover_image))
        title.text = issues[position].title
        description.text = issues[position].description
        date.text = format.format(issues[position].date)
        if ( issues[position].imagePath != null) {
            downloadImage(position)
        }
    }

 private fun downloadImage( position : Int ){
        val downloadIntent = Intent()
        val resultReceiver =  object: ResultReceiver(Handler()){
            override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, bundleResultData : Bundle)
            {
                if ( resultCode == 0 ) {
                    issues[position].imagePath = bundleResultData.getString("path")
                }
            }
        };
        downloadIntent.putExtra(ContentDownloadService.IMAGE, issues[position].imagePath)
        downloadIntent.putExtra(ContentDownloadService.RECEIVER, resultReceiver)
        downloadService.startActivity(downloadIntent);
    }
}
```

When I try and run this in the debugger I get the following message:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:379)
        at com.myapp.models.IssueAdapter.downloadImage(IssueAdapter.kt:72)
```

Stepping in with the debugger shows that `downloadService` *definitely is a real object* when it is called.

Why is Android seeing my service as null when called but showing it as correct in the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> private val downloadService: ContentDownloadService = ContentDownloadService()
> ```

You cannot instantiate Android-lifecycled objects just by calling the constructor. You need to let the framework init them for you. For `Service`s that means calling `startService()` or one of its variants.

> Stepping in with the debugger shows that downloadService definitely is a real object when it is called.
>
> Why is Android seeing my service as null when called but showing it as correct in the debugger?

It's not null as can be seen in the stacktrace. A method in that object fails with NPE since the object itself is not properly initialised. In particular, it's the `mBase` base context in a `ContextWrapper` that is null here.

Comment: That will be it, I bet! I've been so busy picking up Kotlin I'm forgetting my Android basics!

Answer (score 0):

> To this end I pass it a `ContentDownloadService` which extends `IntentService`.

You should NEVER create android framework objects yourself because they contain a lot of internal state which will be uninitialized if they are created this way. By creating it with `val downloadService: ContentDownloadService = ContentDownloadService()` it leaves some internal `Context` variable unset which is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity` is an asynchronous method, so you're likely losing the scope of your IntentService before it's able to launch the activity.  You could try doing

```
downloadService.applicationContext.startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

However, you should consider rethinking your entire approach here.  Normally you only want to launch an activity from another activity.  If your app is in the foreground and this gets called, the system will likely crash with an error saying that activities not started by other activities must have the NEW_TASK flag added to their intents.  The reason is that you will be launching your activity outside the context of your current UI, and therefore will kill the current task and relaunch it with the provided activity.